# Can you use the Ammu-Nation shooting ranges in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In GTA Online, the Ammu-Nation stores with a shooting range still have a different icon on the map from the stores without a shooting range, but when I go into them I don't seem to be able to use the range.

Is the range disabled in GTA Online, or do I need to level up to unlock it?

Comment: I was thinking since GTA Online is quite different from the single player game, should we use separate tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of pressing <kbd>-></kbd> at the door, walk through the door to the range itself. There should be a glowing blue ring at the far end of the room that triggers the shooting range hobby.

It works just like any other job. Once you trigger the event you can invite people to your lobby (or not, solo works too) before launching the session to start shooting. The challenges are different from story mode though, since they are built as competitive challenges intended for more than one player.

Comment: This triggers the hobby. He's looking for it in online mode.

Comment: I did this in online mode.

Comment: Ah thanks! I did go through the door, but didn't notice the blue ring there, I'll try it again

Comment: Don't know how I missed that mission trigger the first time! thanks

Answer (score -2):

The [wiki here](http://gta.wikia.com/Ammu-Nation_Shooting_Range_%28GTA_V%29) shows that you don't need a specific level or requirement to go.

> In Grand Theft Auto V, Shooting Ranges are activities or hobbies you can do.

Hobbies can be preformed at any level. However there is a shooting gallery in GTA V online you can't enter. You can only enter a range in Offline mode.